# Python List Formatting and Updation

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list Eg. a = ["dgbbgfbjhffbjjddvj/n//n//n' "]
How do I remove the trailing new lines i.e. all /n with extra single inverted comma at the end?

Expected result = ["dfgjhgjjhgfjjfgg"] (I typed it randomly)

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem with any of the answers below?

Comment: FYI - Why is voting important? stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use string rstrip() method.

**usage:**

```
str.rstrip([c])
```

where c are what chars have to be trimmed, whitespace is the default when no arg provided.

**example:**

```
a = ['Return a copy of the string\n', 'with trailing characters removed\n\n']                                 
[i.rstrip('\n') for i in a]
```

**result:**

```
['Return a copy of the string', 'with trailing characters removed']
```

**more about strip():**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_rstrip.htm